The proof of the relationship between the R-transform and the Cauchy transform
I am reading  (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-6942-5).
In section 2.4, we define the formal power series
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        M(z) & = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_n z^n, \\
        C(z) & = 1 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \kappa_n z^n,
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $(\alpha_n)$ and $(\kappa_n)$ are moments and cumulants of a non-commutative random variable $a \in \mathscr{A}$. We then prove in Proosition 17 that
\begin{equation}
    M(z) = C(zM(z)).
\end{equation}
And use this result to prove that
$$K(G(z)) = z,$$
where $G$ is the Cauchy transform given by
$$G(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_n}{z^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{z} M\bigg(\frac{1}{z}\bigg),$$
and
$$K(z) = \frac{C(z)}{z} = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \kappa_n z^{n - 1}.$$
The authors then want to prove that $G(K(z)) = z$. In order to do that, they make the following dicsussion:
Let $\mathbb{C} [[ z ]]$ denotes the ring of formal power series in $z$ and $\mathbb{C}((z))$ denotes the ring of formal Laurent series in $z$, i.e., $z K(z) \in \mathbb{C} [[ z ]]$. We know that $M$ and $C$ are in $\mathbb{C} [[ z ]]$, $G \in \mathbb{C} [[ 1 / z ]]$ and $K \in \mathbb{C}((z))$. Therefore,
$K \circ G \in \mathbb{C}((1 / z))$ and $G \circ K \in \mathbb{C}[[ z ]]$. The authors then say that "We then also have $G(K(z)) = z$".
I am confusing about the last sentense. How can we derive that $G(K(z)) = z$? I checked everything and tried directing expanding $G \circ K$ and $K \circ G$ but the formulas are too complex to give me the desired result. Can this conclusion be derived directly?
Thanks for any help.

I have some ideas of the proof. By insert $K \circ G = I$ into $G \circ K$, we have $G \circ K = \big(G \circ K\big)^m$, $\forall m \geq 1$. Thus by comparing the coefficents in ${z^n}$, we must have $G \circ K = I$. But I do not know whether this "proof" is serious.

The relation $M(z) = C(zM(z))$ immediately implies $M(\frac{1}{z}) = C(\frac{1}{z}M(\frac{1}{z}))$ (just replace the formal variable $z$ with the formal variable $z^{-1}$) so that $zG(z)=C(G(z))$ and hence $z =\frac{C(G(z))}{G(z)}$. Thus if we define $K(z) = \frac{C(z)}{z}$ it follows that $K\circ G(z)=z$.
I'm not sure that this is what Mingo and Speicher intended, but I think the following completes the argument:
If $F \in \mathbb C(\!(z)\!)$ and $F=z^{-1}f_1$ where $f_1$ is a unit in $\mathbb C[\![z]\!]$,  then $F$ has a unique left inverse $H(z^{-1}) \in z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z^{-1}]\!]$, that is, there is a unique $H(z^{-1})$ such that $H\circ F = z$. Indeed if $H = \sum_{n \geq 1} h_iz^{-i}$ we must have
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} h_nz^n f_1(z)^{-n} =z
$$
Now setting $c_n(z) = f_1(z)^{-n}\in \mathbb C[\![z]\!]$ and writing $c_n(z) =\sum_{k \geq 0} c^n_kz^k$ we see that $1=h_1c^1_0$ and for $n>1$ we have $h_nc^n_0 + \sum_{j<n} h_jc^j_{n-j} =0$ and hence as $c^n_0 = (c^1_0)^n \neq 0$ (as $f_1$ is a unit) we can always solve this system recursively for $h_n$ and moreover that solution is unique.
But now if we apply the previous paragraph to $F= K$ then we find that there is a unique $H\in \mathbb z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z^{-1}]\!]$ such that $H\circ K = z$. But then
$$
H = H\circ z = H \circ (K \circ G) = (H \circ K) \circ G = z \circ G = G
$$
so that $H =G$. Thus $K\circ G = G \circ K = z$ as required.
Remark: The strategy above works more generally it seems: if $F$ and $H$ are as above, then $H\circ F \in z\mathbb C[\![z]\!]$ while $F \circ H \in z\mathbb C[\![z^{-1}]\!]$. Now for a given $H\in z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z^{-1}]\!]$, say $H =  z^{-1}h_1(z^{-1})$ we may find an $\mathcal F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n-1}\in z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z]\!]$ such that $\mathcal F \circ H = z$. Indeed
$$
(\mathcal F\circ H')(z^{-1}) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^{-n+1}h_1(z^{-1})^{n-1}
$$
and thus just as above, one can solve for the coefficients $a_n$ recursively to see that $H$ has a unique left inverse. Now starting with any $F \in z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z]\!]$ we have shown there is a unique $H \in z^{-1}\mathbb C[\![z^{-1}]\!]$ such that $H \circ F=z$ and a unique $\mathcal F$ such that $\mathcal F \circ H = z$. But then
$$
\mathcal F = \mathcal F \circ z = \mathcal F \circ (H \circ F)= (\mathcal F \circ H) \circ F = z \circ F = F
$$
so that $H$ is actually a two-sided inverse for $F$.

Thanks for your answer. Very clear!
